# Creating a default column using sysdate but getting a character varying error when inserting data

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am creating a table in redshift using a default sysdate column However when I insert data I get a weird expression is of type character varying error. This is the first time I ever ran into this error.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shipments_swp
(
shipment_id                      bigint DISTKEY ENCODE RAW,
user_id                          bigint ENCODE ZSTD,
last_tracking_event_time         timestamp encode zstd,
bd_updated_at                    timestamp default sysdate ENCODE ZSTD
);

Insert into shipments_swp
(
select *
from common.shipments_dim
);
```

The error message is as shown

```
SQL Error [500310] [42804]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "bd_updated_at" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character varying;
```

Comment: Can you add the ddl of shipments_dim as well?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post an example of the timestamp you're trying to insert into that column? It's possible that you need to cast that column as a timestamp before you write it to shipments_swp. I tried a simple test to see that the insert works correctly and I had no problem inserting to it:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table_a (
    ts_a    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSDATE ENCODE ZSTD
);

-- Insert a few different date formats
insert into test_table_a values('2020/05/22');
insert into test_table_a values('2020-05-22');
insert into test_table_a values('2020-05-22 16:12:27.830728');
insert into test_table_a values('2020-05-22 16:06:00');

--- Create a second table and write to that 
--- to mimic the insert behavior from the question

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table_b (
    ts_b    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSDATE ENCODE ZSTD
);

INSERT INTO test_table_b (
    SELECT *
    FROM test_table_a
);

--- This insert succeeds
SELECT * FROM test_table_b;

2020-05-22 16:06:00
2020-05-22 00:00:00
2020-05-22 16:06:56.823844
2020-05-22 00:00:00
```